# How to convert Speech to Text which support multiple language and fast response in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i m used to convert speech to text I speech  sdk and give slow response if any other Sdk is available to give fast response which support multiple language...

if you have any example or other use any other Sdk than Provide me...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

Check out this voice recognition and text-to-speech library 'OpenEars'.

http://www.politepix.com/openears

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Artificial Intelligence expert but with Image Recognition, they use something like Neural Networks where the AI can learn to read characters, usually based on the backward-propagating neural network.

I assume speech recognition is like image recognition but these technologies should be independent.

The only reason why you would need an internet connection that I could think of would be because the developer of the SDK wants the AI results to be collected at the server so the AI technology can learn from these new results and become smarter, just like how Apple's Siri works.

An AI with a bigger pool of data will very likely learn faster than an AI with a smaller pool of data (if the app was to only work on the device, it'll only understand your accent for example, rather than international accents like Apple's Siri)

It seems the Speech SDK you use goes down this path in that all its results are stored on their server.

You probably need to learn Neural Networks AI programming and implement your own or find another library that doesn't use an Internet connection, if you want the Speech recognition to work offline.